# sequenced before:the order of arguments of different functions

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int f(int){cout << "f ";return 0;}
int g(int){cout << "g ";return 0;}
int a(){cout << "a ";return 0;}
int b(){cout << "b ";return 0;}

int main()
{
    f(a()) + g(b());
    return 0;
}
```

I konw a is sequenced before f, b is sequenced before g. f and g are unsequenced.

How many results are there?

1.a f b g

2.b g a f

Example 1 and 2 may happen. How about these?

3. a b f g
4. a b g f
5. b a f g
6. b a g f

Possibly or impossible?

Comment: f and g are indeterminately sequenced (since they are function calls), not unsequenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that's guaranteed is that `b()` will be evaluated before `g()`, and `a()` before `f()`. Those are the only 2 ordering relations that are obeyed. So any output compatible with this ordering is possible. In your case, this means that any outputs from 1 to 6 may happen.